# Mapa do google maps fica cinza, porém quando altero o zoom do navegador volta, o que devo fazer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Então galera, eu tenho 2 partes do sistema em que eu trabalho, onde uso um mapa para mostrar o endereço do imovel ou pessoa. Só que no imovel funciona perfeitamente, mas na pessoa (q tem os mesmos codigos) eu tenho q dar um zoom no navegador que fica perfeito de novo.... Alguém sabe oq pode acontecer isso?
Obrigado !

uma coisa importante q esqueci de mencionar, ele está numa partialView , entao ele está sendo colocado ali enquanto a pagina carrega...

Lembrando que este codigo já existia no sistema eu apenas resolvi alguns problemas.

```
    -edit-3
    var map;
    var marker;
    /* ============================ MÉTODOS PARA O MAPA ============================ */
    function initializeMap() {
        latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-15.796892001990338, -47.890573438861864);
        var myOptions = { 
            zoom: 14, 
            center: latlng, 
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        createMarker(latlng);

        var position = undefined;
        <% var endereco = this.Model.Endereco;
        if (endereco.Latitude.HasValue && endereco.Longitude.HasValue)
        {%>
               position = new google.maps.LatLng(
               <%: endereco.Latitude.GetValueOrDefault().ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) %>, 
               <%: endereco.Longitude.GetValueOrDefault().ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) %>);
               changeMarkerPosition(position);
               <%}
        else
        {%>
        changeMarkerPositionByAddress(getEnderecoCompleto());
        <%}%>

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        $("#mapaContato").css('display','block');
    }

    function createMarker(position) {
        map.setCenter(position);
        markerOptions = {
            draggable: true,
            map: map,
            position: position,
            visible: true
        };
        marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'position_changed', OnMarkerPositionChanged);
    }

    function changeMarkerPosition(position) {
        marker.setPosition(position);
        map.setCenter(position);
    }

    function changeMarkerPositionByAddress(address) {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address, region: "BR" }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                local = results[0].geometry.location;
                changeMarkerPosition(local);
            } else if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
                alert("Não foi localizada uma coordenada geográfica para este endereço.\nFavor localizar o ponto manualmente no mapa.");
            } else {
                alert("A busca no mapa resultou em um erro inesperado.\nErro: " + status);
            }
        });
    }

    function OnMarkerPositionChanged() {
        var local = marker.getPosition();
        updateMarkerPosition(local);
    }

    function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
        $("#Endereco_Latitude").val(doubleToString(latLng.lat()));
        $("#Endereco_Longitude").val(doubleToString(latLng.lng()));
    }

    function doubleToString(value) {
        <% var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        var formatInfo = (System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo)culture.GetFormat(typeof(System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo));
        if (formatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator == "," && formatInfo.NumberGroupSeparator == ".")
        {%>
               return value.toString().replace(".", ",");
               <%}
        else
        {%>
        return value.toString();
        <%}
    %>
    }
```

Comment: Precisaria ver o código para entender melhor. Quando o mapa fica cinza eu uso resize, google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); que ele volta, mas precisa ver no seu código quando está ficando cinza.

Comment: Coloquei la ! :D

Comment: Como vi que está usando a variável "map" como global nas funções acredito que de certo colocar map.addListener('idle', function () { google.maps.event.trigger(this, 'resize');}); depois do map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions); . Essa função fará que toda vez que o mapa mudar de posição ele tente recarregar, fazendo assim com que o mapa não fique mais cinza.

Comment: Se não fora isso pode ser pq a div que recebe o mapa não esteja aparecendo no momento em que instancia o mapa. O google maps não trabalha em div escondida, vc deve mostrar a div e depois tentar dar um new google.maps.Map

Comment: aaaa deve ser justamente essa segunda questao, pois como vc pode ver, eu dou um ''display: block" pra aparecer depois q recarrega. porem ja fiz o teste de retira-la. Obrigado ja voltarei com o feedback

Comment: AndréVicente desculpa a demora eu tive q sair de emergencia, mas agora só quando eu mexo no mouse q ele funciona. se ele apenas carregar a pagina ele continua cinza, se eu mexer, ele funciona

Answer (score 2):

Resolvi o problema, no caso, o mapa tava sendo renderizado dentro de uma partial view. Entao eu coloquei o metodo para inicializar o mapa na view q carrega as partial view. E então quando ele iniciou ele renderizou normalmente.
Obrigado André usa resposta me ajudou nisso!